# Проблема с горячими клавишами авто импорта alt+enter в Pycharme

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains, hotkeys

Раньше все работало, потом резко перестало вроде ничего не менял,[image: скрин настройки авто-импорта], в настройках все включено обновился до последний версии выделяю курсором, то что надо импортировать ничего не происходит, при нажатии правой кнопкой и выбора Show Context Actions, пишет No context actions available at this location[image: введите сюда описание изображения],два часа пытался исправить ситуацию читал документацию JetBrains, ничего не нашел может кто-то сталкивался или знает пути решения, заранее Благодарен!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Раньше в пайчарме когда я наследовал какой-то класс  из разных модов джанго, я при нажатии alt+enter на этот класс автоматически его импортировал, потов в моменте эта функция перестала работать, я не знаю с чем это связано.